# odoo manufacturing transfer

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

We are using odoo manufacturing and Inventory modules. We have different 2 warehouse and locations (for example WH A and WH B).

when I manufacture on WH B.

If there are not enough raw material then it can be purchased. However, if there are enough product on WHA, I want to create automatically Transfer request from WHA to WHB.

thank you for your help

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: It's simple my manufacturing location is WH/B and stock location is WH/A. I need to transfer raw material manually but I want to create stock operation for my Raw materials when I produce a product on WH/B. Is it possible or not? How can manage this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my pleasure to help you.
I will let you know how to solve this case in both V8 And V9

### Solution For odoo version v9

**Step 1 Make configuration**

> To do the configuration you can go to **Inventory -> Configuration ->
>   Setting->** 
>   **Location and Warehouse**
>
> 1. **Multi-Location** -> Manage several locations per warehouse
> 2. **Routes** -> Advanced routing of products using rules

[image: Step-1-Configuration-v9]

**Step 2 Create the WareHouse**

> Create the 2 Ware House Named (for example WH A and WH-B) as per your
>   requirement.
>
> TO do so you can go to this path Inventory **-> Configuration ->
>   Setting -> Warehouse Management -> Warehouse**

[image: Step-2-Create-WareHouse-v9]

**Step 3 Define the resupply warehouse**

> TO do so you can go to this path Inventory **-> Configuration ->
>   Setting -> Warehouse Management -> Warehouse**

[image: Step-3-Define-Resupply-rule-v9]

**Step 4 Create Product**

[image: Step-4-Create-Product-v9]

**Step 5 Configure the Routs**

> To configure the routes You can go to Inventory **-> Product ->(In
>   selected or newly create product) Inventory -> Routs -> select the
>   appropriate route**

[image: Step-5-Configure-Route-v9]

**Hint:**

> You can also go to the 
>   **Purchases -> Product ->(In selected or new created product) Inventory -> Routs -> select the appropriate route**

**Step 5 Define new reordering rule for the procurement**

> TO do so you can go to **Inventory -> Configuration -> Routes ->
>   Select your route/ create new**

[image: Step-6-Define-reorderig-rule-v9]

**Step 6 Define Push Rule/ Define Routes**

> TO do so you can go to **Inventory -> Configuration -> Routes -> Select
>   your route/ create new -> Push Rule**

[image: Step-7-Define-push-rule-v9]

### Solution For odoo version v8

Go to this link for V8

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju7MtCXlCFk

Now by performing the sales & other operation, you can check your issue will solve. still,  If you are having problem Comment here. I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it

Comment: Plz, Upvote and select the answer. It will sure helpful.

Comment: I want to ask something more. I need control firstly WHb on manufacturing location and after there is no stock in WHb then It should create transfer from WHa.

Comment: I didn't  get what you want to ask.

Comment: I manufacture on WHB I want to firstly odoo control of WHB stock. if there is no stock on WHB then Control of WHA stocks. WHen ı was confşgurate with your answer, My odoo didnt control WHB stock.

Comment: In answer, the configuration is there I have tried it it's working properly at my site.  Might be you are doing mistake in configuration.